# Imagick::annotateImage PHP causing Error Code 204 on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, imagick

I redid a PHP GAE project of mine using the GD library to the Magick library. 
The updated code works fine in the GAE Launcher v1.9.23, however when deployed I'm getting in the browser:

*Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.*

In the Google Dashboard under Monitoring→Logs, I'm getting:

*A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)*

I stripped out all the code and am still getting the error with just:

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFont( ABSPATH . 'banners/ttf_fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf' );
$draw->setFillColor ( new ImagickPixel( 'white' ) );

$temp_img = new Imagick();
$temp_img->newImage( 100, 100, new ImagickPixel( 'green' ) );
$temp_img->annotateImage( $draw, 20, 20, 0, 'Hello world' );
$temp_img->setImageFormat('png');

header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );        
echo $temp_img;
```

Does GAE require a different approach for embedding text in an image?

Comment: Have you configured your application to use the extension? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#dynamically_loadable_extensions

Comment: Most probably https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11854

Comment: @Danack: Yes, I have tried both recommended `extension = "imagick.so"` and Magick doc recommended `extension=imagick.so`. No change. To be clear, if I comment out the `annotateImage` statement, it works and generates a green 100 x 100 box. This is appears to be specifically with font manipulation.

Comment: @Mars: Yes, I think it's related as I'm guessing it's related to the TTF processing. Maybe resource related pertaining to PHP version of Imagick based on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520224/optimizing-imagick-annotateimage  Thanks for the link - I'll monitor that. Not sure if I should be happy, or sad I spent all Sunday on it...

Comment: Has this been solved?  Having the exact same issue with latest app engine php sdk.  Works in dev but not production.